Flutter app restarts after saving code with "Ctrl+S" when using go_router
I'm developing a Flutter app using go_router for navigation, and I'm encountering an issue during development when I save my code using "Ctrl+S". The page unexpectedly reloads, and the app restarts, even though I expect to stay on the same page.
Here's what's happening:
When I click the "Save" button (or press "Ctrl+S"), the app reloads or restarts.
After migrating to go_router, this behavior occurs consistently, and the app always restarts after every save.
I would like the app to stay on the same page without restarting after saving my code.
What I've tried:
Ensuring that the GoRouter is only initialized once and doesn't re-initialize during hot reload.
Double-checking if state management or routing setup is causing the page reload.
Using Flutter DevTools to inspect hot reload behavior, but the app still restarts.
My go_router configuration looks like this:
final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/',
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (context, state) => const HomePage(),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/details',
      builder: (context, state) => const DetailsPage(),
    ),
  ],
);

Has anyone else encountered this issue with go_router during development, and how can I prevent the app from restarting or reloading after every save? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

if you are using VScode go to settings then Keyboard Shortcuts and put this in the search "ctrl+s" with quotes to see what the things that shortcut do and you can change it
